# Moving table column using position:absolute breaks consistent row heights

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a table that allows me to scroll through unlimited columns on the right with the left two columns locked in place using position:absolute. Clicking a link on a column gives that column the class of .locked and removes the same class from column #2 essentially swapping them over.

Jquery:

```
function lockThis(n) {
    if (n != lockedCol) {
        $("#test tr td").removeClass('locked');
        $("#test tr td .lockLink").addClass("glyphicon-circle-arrow-left");
        $("#test tr td:nth-child(" + n + ")").addClass('locked');
        $("#test tr td:nth-child(" + n + ") .lockLink").removeClass("glyphicon-circle-arrow-left");
        lockedCol = n;
   }
}

lockedCol = 0;
lockThis(2);
```

css:

```
 td {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px 0;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   padding: 5px;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(1) {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: auto;
   width: 90px;
   min-width: 90px;
   z-index: 3;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(n+2) {
   min-width: 110px;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(2) {
   background: #ffccdd;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(3) {
   background: #ffddcc;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(4) {
   background: #ffeebb;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(5) {
   background: #aaffbb;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(6) {
   background: #ccddff;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(7) {
   background: #aabbff;
 }

 #test tr td:nth-child(8) {
   background: #bbaaff;
 }

 #test tr td.locked {
   position: absolute;
   left: 90px;
   top: auto;
   width: 100px;
 }

 #test {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   // border-top: 3px solid #0099ff;
   table-layout: fixed
 }

 .tableHolder {
   width: 110px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   margin-left: 200px;
   overflow-y: visible;
   padding-bottom: 1px;
 }

 @media (max-width: 439px) {
   #compareTableBox {
     width: 312px
   }
 }

 @media (min-width: 440px) {
   .tableHolder {
     width: 220px;
   }
   #compareTableBox {
     width: 422px
   }
 }

 @media (min-width: 550px) {
   .tableHolder {
     width: 330px;
   }
   #compareTableBox {
     width: 532px
   }
 }

 @media (min-width: 660px) {
   .tableHolder {
     width: 440px;
   }
   #compareTableBox {
     width: 642px
   }
 }

 #compareTableBox {
   position: relative;
   margin: auto;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

html

```
<body>

  <div id="compareTableBox">

    <div class="tableHolder">
      <table id="test">
        <tr>
          <td class="leftCol">Features</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(2)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Red</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(3)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Orange</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(4)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Yellow</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(5)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Green</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(6)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Blue</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(7)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Indigo</td>
          <td class="contentCol"><span onclick="lockThis(8)" class="lockLink glyphicon"></span> Violet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="leftCol">Bits</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="leftCol">Pieces</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="leftCol">Odds</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">no</td>
          <td class="contentCol">yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="leftCol">Sods</td>
          <td class="contentCol">12</td>
          <td class="contentCol">12</td>
          <td class="contentCol">24</td>
          <td class="contentCol">3</td>
          <td class="contentCol">12</td>
          <td class="contentCol">24</td>
          <td class="contentCol">3</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75audqcf/13/

This works nicely until I have differing heights in the table cells. Then it breaks. The cells on the left don't keep their heights, moving columns out using absolute seems to stop that column affecting the rest of the table. Filling one cell with a lot of text does this.

https://jsfiddle.net/75audqcf/14/

can anyone suggest a way around this? This will be used with variable content so I can't hard-code the heights and I need to keep the widths fixed so that two coloured columns will always be visible on a 320px wide screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already embracing the side scroll, don't even let the text wrap which is causing that funky line break, add this to your CSS:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

```
#test tr td:nth-child(1) {
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: none;}

#test tr td.locked {
    height: 100%;}

#compareTableBox {
    overflow-y:hidden;}

td {
    vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: That would do it but I'd like to keep the column widths as they are. The intention is to make this a product comparison so I always want to be able to see at least three columns (2 + the first headings column) on a small screen (320px wide)

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot better in the initial form but when the column containing the larger text moves over to the left, it collapses, the table taking row height from the cells on the right that haven't been detached with position:absolute. Currently thinking I may have to run a jquery to detect the height of each cell in the .locked column and then set that for each cell in the table if it's different.

Comment: ... which I did and it seems to work :)  
https://jsfiddle.net/franki23/75audqcf/19/